# Timeout in setupProxy works in localhost but not in dokku deployement application

Tags: node.js, proxy, timeout, dokku

I'm working on an application in NodeJS and React for my studies and I have a problem :

When I'm using my application in localhost, the timeout for my long time request post (20/30 minutes) works (write in setupProxy.js file). But in the application deployed on Dokku, this timeout doesn't work (request fail after 1 minute with the error : "*POST 504 (Gateway Time-out)*"). I think Dokku has a timeout by default but I'm not sure and I didn't find out how can I fix it.

My code :

**setupProxy.js**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
 var port;
  if (process.env.PORT) {
    port = process.env.PORT;
  } else {
    port = 5000;
  }

  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware('/api/students', {
      target: `http://localhost:${port}`,
      timeout: 3840000,
    })
  );
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
      target: `http://localhost:${port}`,
    })
  );
};
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

//Connect Database
connectDB();

//Set the limit  higher
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

//Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/admins', require('./routes/api/admins'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'));
app.use('/api/students', require('./routes/api/students'));
app.use('/api/email', require('./routes/api/email'));

// Serve static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
//Look on the heroku app for the port OR take de default port 5000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

Thank you in advance for your help !
Camille.

Answer (score 1):

Dokku uses nginx to proxy requests, which I think has a default timeout of 60 seconds.

Looks like there is a plugin you can use to modify this timeout on a per-app basis [here](https://github.com/danielslee/dokku-nginx-proxy-timeout). This would also be a good candidate for adding support directly upstream.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried that but I didn't have rights to do this on my school server. I will ask to my teacher. I hope it will works !

Comment: Feel free to have your teacher post a feature request for this upstream in the Dokku project, definitely seems like a good thing to add :)